# Существуют ли адекватные реализации парсинга HTML в Qt?

Tags: c++, html, qt, парсер

Задача простая: распарсить `html` и легко выбирать из него элементы. Желательно `XPath`.

Пример: на главной странице `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/` есть текст `Лучшие вопросы`
Выбрать его легко через `XPath` : 
`/html/body[@class='home-page new-topbar']/div[@class='container']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='mainbar']/div[@class='subheader']/h1[@id='h-top-questions']`

Но как я не старался найти в Qt средств для такой задачи - не нашел. 
Знатоки, что посоветуете использовать?

Comment: Может, не в тему, но если вы хотите вытаскивать данные именно со Stack Overflow, то возиться с парсингом HTML не обязатьельно, лучше использовать [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Handling_HTML

Comment: Я же Вам в предыдущем вопросе дал ссылку на `QXmlQuery`, который поддерживает `XPath`, что не так?

Comment: @klopp, смотрел, ничего там подходящего нет.

Comment: @ixSci, не завелось. Пример предоставите?

Comment: [Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286842/how-do-i-run-xpath-queries-in-qt) есть пример. Сам я с `QXmlQuery` дела не имел. И ещё [один](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675907/how-can-i-use-qts-qxmlquery-to-run-xpath-queries-on-a-local-file)

Comment: @ixSci, речь идет не о `XML`, а о `html`. Это ведь разные вещи и синтаксис иной.

Comment: HTML это набор тегов, если HTML корректный, то он должен разбираться с помощью XPath. Плюс я Вас не понимаю, с одной стороны Вы спрашиваете про XPath, а потом приводите различия XML и HTML - XPath это технология для XML, а не HTML(в общем виде)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам и ответил на предыдущий Ваш вопрос ixSci, можно использовать [QXmlQuery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html), но html-исходник должен быть валиден с точки зрения xml, в обратном случае корректная работа не гарантируется.

Тем не менее, для валидации можно воспользоваться, например, библиотекой [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/). Написана она на языке C, что подчас не слишком удобно для Qt-проектов. В этом случае можете использовать какой-нибудь класс-обёртку, созданный [по примеру](http://blog.sjinks.pro/c-cpp/qt/942-html-parser-qt/), либо вообще написать свой собственный.

Разумеется, нужно иметь в виду, что если целевой сайт активно использует аякс (ajax), то его dom-структура, полученная при обычном http-запросе, может быть, мягко говоря, урезана и содержать отнюдь не весь контент, который показывается в обычном браузере. Для того, чтобы получить с такого сайта в том числе и подгружаемые данные потребуется также и поддержка интерпретатора javascript, который и займётся выполнением соответствующих задач. А это уже ближе к уровню браузерного движка. Начиная с версии Qt 5.4, их два: QtWebKit и QWebEngine. Первый, кстати, в будущих релизах Qt будет отмечен как устаревший, а второй постепенным вводом нового функционала заменит его полностью. Однако QWebEngine пока не предоставляет средств для доступа к структуре вебстраницы, поэтому на сегодняшний день выбор только за QtWebKit, коим и возможно пользоваться в полной мере.

Документация по классам, составляющим QtWebKit, очень подробная. Также имеются и примеры, поставляемые вместе с Qt-дистрибутивом и раскрывающие основные моменты, в т.ч. и парсинга вебстраниц.

Comment: все из выше перечисленного подробно рассматривал. `QtWebKit` не хочу использовать (первая причина вес, вторая - тело страницы я получаю через обычный запрос `QNAM`)

Comment: libxml2 враппер тоже использовал, но он не завелся.  Действительно не парсит тело.

Comment: В таком случае берёте любой C/C++ парсер, который устраивает и пишете к нему враппер для интеграции в Qt. Если будете спрашивать "какой парсер взять" - сразу пишите какие чем не устраивают и что конкретно они не парсят. А если нужно парсить то, где есть API (как здесь) - и напрягаться не стоит :)

Comment: @klopp, да не в том дело. Просто обидно, что существующих библиотек мало под эту платформу.

Comment: Да какая разница-то? Обидно/не обидно это вообще не критерий. Достаточно того, что есть куча библиотек как на C, так и на плюсах. А вставить их в любое сишное или плюсовое окружение - вообще не вопрос.